# Can I use separate web.config file over SSL?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, web-config

I'll start out by saying I'm new to SSL and how it works in ASP.NET/WCF.

I have a web service that is currently accessed without SSL that I need to change to accept traffic over http and https. My web.config refers to 3rd party URLs that are using http. These URLs are returned to the client and then accessed requested through JavaScript. If a web site which is using SSL calls my web service using SSL, I need to return the https versions of these 3rd party URLs so that the browser doesn't display at "mixed security" warning.

Does anyone have any advice on how best to achieve this? One thought I had was to create a parallel site that handles all of the ssl traffic, but I wasn't sure how feasable this was in IIS6 (which is waht we're using for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep it to one web.config file.  I assume that you are trying to avoid the "This page contains secure and insecure content" warnings?

You can store your URLs in the web.config file without the protocol (e.g. www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com)  Then when you go to use the URLs in the code, after you pull them from the web.config but before you display them, use the Request IsSecureConnection property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx

For example:

```
((Request.IsSecureConnection)?"https://":"http://") + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["theURL"]
```

Or you can do it with javascript (this is how Google Analytics does it):

```
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
```

Then later they just use the gaJsHost "prefix" to fetch the resource..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but as long as you don't have your IIS site configured to  only allow SSL traffic you should be fine. Your services will still work over SSL and non SSL traffic.

You should use rewrite rules to make sure that all users are directed to SSL
http://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html

If you use the rewrite module in IIS7 as per the instructions I linked above you can ensure that anyone visiting your site is automatically redirected to SSL.

Comment: I have edited the question, which wasn't clear. My issue is I would like to have one web.config for my non-ssl traffic and a different one for my ssl traffic on the same site.

Answer (score 0):

Always use https to reference files, and problem solved. Otherwise, maybe start using urls w/o protocol - e.g. `//somesite.com/somefile.html` - and the browser will use the protocol of the current page.